# Can I get this lengthy comments argument removed from my answer?

Tags: discussion

https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/5805/4197

I asked people to move the discussion to chat, but no one listened :)

Comment: DId you flag? A mod will pick it up, it just might take some time ;) --> They were removed three minutes ago..

Comment: Chris, most users will not voluntarily take something to chat. First, some don't know how to create a chat room. Second, commenters think their comment is important, and don't want it sent into the ether. Flag!

Comment: @anongoodnurse Yes, I accepted "flagging" as the right answer.  I would delete this question, but it might be useful to others as a guide to what to do.

Comment: @ChrisSunami - It is absolutely useful to have a number of these types of questions for newcomers, so please do. I just found it to be an idealistic request, and I know I was involved, so... Sorry about that. :-/

Comment: @anongoodnurse  Your comment was on topic and useful, I edited my answer because of it. It was everything that came afterwards that was a problem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can raise a moderator flag for this** :D

I've moved/deleted them for you but it can get a bit... weird since someone *did* create a chat room... and the time stamps decide the ordering of things and... they use the time stamps for when the comments were moved to chat, not originally posted on the site...

Yeah, sorry. The move comments to chat tool is... not great.

They're all in the chat room linked on your answer.

Comment: Follow up question.. I did suspect the rest of the comments were going to get swept up too, but I didn't realize the tool would dump them in the same room.. in the future should I just wait for a mod to put everything in chat so it doesn't get more confusing? Or should I still move my part to chat asap?

Comment: The tool doesn't. I moved them there manually to keep them all in one place. If you want to move to chat, please do. I wish there were a more useful way to do this but many proposals have been considered. Some of them are probably in a queue to implement but for right now I had to choose between having two chat rooms or one.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the explanation! I'm still learning the finer points of stack exchange :)